# Select2 autocomplete not working with WP 5.6

Tags: jquery, wordpress, jquery-select2

I have this code:

```
jQuery('#eventClienteId').select2({
                        dropdownParent: jQuery("#formEvento"),
                        ajax: {
                            url: '<?php echo AJAX_URL; ?>?action=aj_cliente_search',
                            data: function (params) {
                                return {
                                    q: params.term, // search term
                                };
                            },
                            dataType: 'json',
                            delay: 250,
                            processResults: function (data) {
                            //results: function (data) {
                                // parse the results into the format expected by Select2
                                
                                return {
                                    results: jQuery.map(data.items, function(obj) {
                                        return { 
                                            id              : obj.id, 
                                            text            : obj.text ,
                                            first_name      : obj.first_name,
                                            last_name       : obj.last_name,
                                            contact_email   : obj.contact_email,
                                            contact_number  : obj.contact_number,
                                            cf_piva         : obj.cf_piva
                                        };
                                    })
                                };
                            },
                            cache: true,
                            placeholder: 'Cerca per nome, cognome o CF/P.IVA...',
                            minimumInputLength: 2
                        }
                        }).on('change', function(e) {
                            
                            ...
                            
                        });
```

which works great with WP 5.5.3 but not with WP 5.6. Anyone stuck on this as well?
I have looked on console with FF Developer Edition: not ajax call is being fired.

Comment: WP 5.6 introduces some jQuery changes more here: https://wptavern.com/wordpress-5-6-will-ship-with-another-major-jquery-change
https://make.wordpress.org/support/2020/12/handling-potential-jquery-issues-in-wordpress-5-6/